# Authentication in Sharepoint - Could you explain me?

Tags: deployment, authentication

Im learning SP and i have everything installed and running. The only thing im not sure about is authentication:

1)If you run your SP installation on LAN and the only users who can access it, is people from your domain(AD users). Users will be authenticated by kerberous(by domain login), is this correct? If not, explain me please.

2)Is it possible to authenticate users other than the domain users, created in users and computers?

Answer (score 2):

1) yes

2) yes

Okay now I have said yes and yes I will explain.

In SharePoint you can configure multiple authentication providers, in fact local users will also automatically work out of the box as will AD users because SharePoint uses local accounts itself, (i.e. system account).

Therefore any domain or local user made can authenticate.

SharePoint is also flexible. To the point were you can use any authentication provider you wish as long as it works with a Forms or a Claims based interface. This is straight forward to set up (Although somewhat lengthy) but this means you can work with any authentication portal provider you wish.

This is a basic overview and there are many authentication diagrams available on MSDN and Technet.